# Valgrind trying to read user files for debug information

Tags: valgrind

I'm running code that `mmap()` a file using Valgrind, and it is giving me an error:

```
--23254-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--23254-- When reading debug info from /tmp/db/test.txt:
--23254-- can't read file to inspect ELF header
```

The code in question is about as simple as you can get it to be:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
 
int main() {
    int fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_DSYNC|O_DIRECT|O_CLOEXEC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
 
    if(fd == -1) { 
        printf("file can't be opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int ret = ftruncate(fd, 256*1024);
    if(ret == -1){
        printf("file can't be extended\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("a\n");
    char* buf = mmap(0, 1024*64, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED , fd, 0);
    if(!buf){
        printf("cannot map\n");
        return 1;
    }
 
    munmap(buf, 1024*64);
    close(fd);
 
    return 0;
}
```

To reproduce on my machine, I run: `clang a.c && valgrind ./a.out`

Versions:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.16.1
```

Running Valgrind under `strace` gives:

```
mmap(0x4e4d000, 65536, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0) = 0x4e4d000
statx(3, "", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_EMPTY_PATH, STATX_ALL, {stx_mask=STATX_ALL, stx_attributes=0, stx_mode=S_IFREG|0600, stx_size=262144, ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/fd/3", "/tmp/db/test.txt", 4096) = 16
statx(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/db/test.txt", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_ALL, {stx_mask=STATX_ALL, stx_attributes=0, stx_mode=S_IFREG|0600, stx_size=262144, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, 0x10032c68a0, 1024, 0)       = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
getpid()                                = 23260
write(1027, "--23260-- WARNING: Serious error"..., 57--23260-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
) = 57
getpid()                                = 23260
write(1027, "--23260-- When reading debug inf"..., 57--23260-- When reading debug info from /tmp/db/test.txt:
```

So it looks like the `pread64()` code is failing, but I can't figure out why that is the case, or why it would cause Valgrind to give this error.

Any ideas? All that I can find is old bugs that were fixed years ago

**update**

FWIW, I'm pretty sure that the issue is around the use of O_DIRECT and alignment of memory.
Note that in the call to pread64() , the buffer isn't 4KB aligned, which is usually required for O_DIRECT.
I assume that this generates the error and the rest of the issue.

** update 2 **

Running this with: `clang a.c && valgrind  --trace-syscalls=yes  ./a.out` gives the following output

```
SYSCALL[16927,1](257) sys_openat ( 4294967196, 0x402004(test.txt), 545346, 384 ) --> [async] ...
SYSCALL[16927,1](257) ... [async] --> Success(0x3)
SYSCALL[16927,1](77) sys_ftruncate ( 3, 262144 ) --> [async] ...
SYSCALL[16927,1](77) ... [async] --> Success(0x0)
SYSCALL[16927,1](9) sys_mmap ( 0x0, 262144, 1, 1, 3, 0 )--16927-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--16927-- When reading debug info from /tmp/test.txt:
--16927-- can't read file to inspect ELF header
 --> [pre-success] Success(0x4a4d000)
SYSCALL[16927,1](11) sys_munmap ( 0x4a4d000, 262144 )[sync] --> Success(0x0)
```

Comment: Not related to valgrind, but there is a bug in your code: `mmap` on error returns `MAP_FAILED`, not `NULL`, so `if(!buf)` is the wrong test for mmap failure.

Comment: Correct, forgot about this, thanks. The real code is testing against `MAP_FAILED`, this is just to show the valgrind issue

Comment: What do you get with `valgrind --trace-syscalls=yes` ? I can't reproduce this on Fedora 33 with clang 11.

Comment: Paul - see update 2 in the question

Comment: More details: https://ayende.com/blog/192705-A/the-bug-in-valgrind?key=3870fd6e061e4a78bba74495d3761b0d